# Angular: Wait for ActivatedRoute to be processed?

Tags: angular

**TL;DR: How can I tell when the ActivatedRoute has finished parsing the QueryParams, even if there are none?**

In my Angular 13 application, I have a need to obtain an optional query parameter before I initialise a service which communicates with the server.

This logic occurs in the root component (because I cannot be sure which page the visitor will land on), so the component is loaded before the routing is initialised. For this reason, `this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap` is empty in both the `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit` events.

I know that I can subscribe to the observable returned by `this.route.queryParamMap.subscribe`, and this works fine when there are query parameters in the url, however this does not fire if there are no QueryParams available - and due to this, I don't know for sure when the parsing is complete and therefore when to commence connection to the server.

I have tried setting `initialNavigation` to `enabledBlocking` but this doesn't seem to help, the queryParams are still not available until some time after the ngAfterViewInit event is called.

My fallback solution is to parse the query string myself, but I don't want to pull in another url parsing library when Angular has a compliant parser built in.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there isn't `ngOnViewInit` lifecycle hook, did you mean `ngAfterViewInit`?

Comment: Sorry yes, correcting

Comment: Can you add the code you tried?

Comment: So if exists this optional queryParam or not, either way you need to call the service right? You just want to validate that indeed there is no optional queryParam value to get in order to call the service, is this correct?

Comment: Is not possible to subscribe to route changes, split the url and find the param you need? If present then you start the service, if not present and debounce time is something like 5000 then start anyway? `this.router.events.pairwise().subscribe()`

Comment: @JoosepParts: This is on initial load, so there aren't necessarily going to be any route change events

Comment: @TomMettam I believe Router is also injected on Root, so even if it's initial load you can still subscribe to route changes? You also have to do it close to root, perhaps in AppComponent.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The working solution was to listen for the `ActivationEnd` router event, which fires after the router has finished initializing.

Thanks to [@Joosep Parts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72334405/1872867) for tipping me off about Router.events

```
private initialized = false;

public constructor(private readonly router: Router, private readonly route: ActivatedRoute)
{
    this.router.events.subscribe((data) =>
    {
        if (!this.initialized && data instanceof ActivationEnd)
        {
            this.initialized = true;
            console.log('Initial query param keys: ' + JSON.stringify(route.snapshot.queryParamMap.keys, null, 4));
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I listened to all router events and used it to find some params. If optional param jwt is present we can run the service.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {

      console.log(event)
      const urlParts = event?.url?.split('?');

      const jwtValue = urlParts?.find((part) => part.includes('jwt'));

      if (jwtValue) {
        console.warn('Run service, jwt is:', jwtValue);
        // go to service
      }

    });
  }

  navigate() {
    this.router.navigate(['authenticate'], { queryParams: { jwt: '123' } });
  }
}
```

Here is an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-navigate-with-query-params-atevru?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: What's the purpose of the navigate() method?

Comment: This code has issues but I think you've pointed me in the right direction with `router.events`, thanks

Comment: `navigate()` is just for demo purpouses on html click listener `(click)="navigate(0)"`. Focus on the `.subscribe()` part of the demo.